# Reflection from inside Java

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have a Java Library, and I created a Bindings DLL using Xamarin. Everything works, but I have small issue with reflection. Here is the simplified view

In Java :

```
JavaClass {

    public Object delegate;
    public String methodName;

    public void executeMethod() {
        delegate.getClass().getMethod(methodName).invoke(); //simplified
    }
}
```

In Xamarin:

```
CSharpActivity {

    protected override void onCreate(Bundle b){

        JavaClass c = new JavaClass ();
        c.Delegate = this;
        c.MethodName = "MethodOnMe";
        c.ExecuteMethod();
    }

    public void MethodOnMe(){
    }
}
```

This chokes spectacularly, because `methodOnMe` is not found by Java. Any way how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Ok For those of you who stumble on this - need to add the Export Attribute.

```
[Java.Interop.Export("MethodOnMe")]
public void MethodOnMe(){
```

In addition to the above, resolution to a few other issues that we encountered here:
http://blog.androidjetpack.com/post/Android-DataGrid-Xamarin-Support-Added-Java-Binding-Project-Issues.aspx